# Alignment problem using align environement and \phantom

Tags: align

The following code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A &\leq B \cdot C \cdot \int D
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq B \cdot {}}
    C \cdot \int D
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq B \cdot C {}}
    \cdot \int D
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq B \cdot C \cdot \int {}}
    D
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  A &\leq \fbox{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq {}}
    \cdot \int \fbox{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq \cdot \int {}}
    \fbox{ccccccccccccccccccc}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

gives
[image: weird alignments]

In the first case the alignments work exactly as I would expect.
But why in the second case the boxes of b's and c's are not aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second `align` you're forgetting the empty atom after `\leq`:

```
\begin{align*}
  A &\leq \fbox{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq {}}
    \cdot \int \fbox{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
  \\&
    \phantom{{} \leq {}\cdot \int {}}
    \fbox{ccccccccccccccccccc}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

When you have **Rel** **Bin** **Op**, the **Bin** atom is changed into **Ord** (think to `$a \leq -\log b$`), so the spacing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you align it directly to the point where you want it, and then adjust the first row accordingly?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A \leq B \cdot C \cdot \int &D
  \\
  C \cdot \int &D
  \\
  \cdot \int &D
  \\
  &D
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
   A \leq \hspace{2.2em} &\hspace{-2em}\fbox{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
  \\
    \cdot \int &\fbox{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
  \\
    &\fbox{ccccccccccccccccccc}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Please not that I added `2.2em` before the `&`, instead of `2em`, because it gives a space between the `\leq` and the box, and it looks a bit better, at least to me.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I guess I could do that in this specific example. But that does not answer my question. Why is the alignment working in the first example but not the second?

Comment: And the environment `align` is designed such that you put the alignment before the relation symbol. It gives then the right spacing around it. It looks weird to me to write `&` any where else.